# Why is the natural map from maximal to reduced C star algebra surjective?

Tags: c-star-algebras

In the book "Kazhdan' property (T)" [the third book in this link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan's_property_(T)), page 438,
One sentence is "the regular representation defines a surjective *-homomorphism $\lambda_G: C^{*}(G)\to C^{*}_\text{red}(G)$".

I understand the existence of such homomorphism, but I do not understand why it is onto, could anyone help explain it or provide any reference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is onto because the image contains a generating set for $C^*_{\text{red}}(G)$, and any C$^*$-algebra homomorphism maps a C$^*$-algebra onto a C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: I see, the second fact you mentioned is also used to show $||.||_{max}$ is the largest norm on algebraic tensor of two C star algebras, thanks a lot!